# How to set locate on all grouped routes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, localization

I am using Laravel and I have  grouped routes that all of them are for dashboard
so I want to change language with url something like this :

> http://localhost:8000/ar/dashboard/shop/dashboard-shop
>   http://localhost:8000/fa/dashboard/shop/dashboard-shop
>   http://localhost:8000/en/dashboard/shop/dashboard-shop

```
    Route::namespace('Dashboard')->prefix('{locale}/dashboard')-

>middleware('auth')->group(function ($locale) {
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

but it does not get $locate as a string "en" or "fa" it gives me this object

```
Illuminate\Routing\Router {#26 ▼
  #events: Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher {#27 ▶}
  #container: Illuminate\Foundation\Application {#2 ▶}
  #routes: Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection {#29 ▶}
  #current: null
  #currentRequest: null
  #middleware: array:9 [▶]
  #middlewareGroups: array:2 [▶]
  +middlewarePriority: array:6 [▶]
  #binders: []
  #patterns: []
  #groupStack: array:2 [▶]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve any router parms simply by

```
request(‘locale’)
```

Another option instead of making prefix for all your routes you can handle localization from middleware simply by checking if ?locale exist and then change the locale

Comment: this gives me null

Answer (score 0):

Parameters don't get passed to the `group` callback function. The `Router` gets passed in:

```
->group(function ($router) { ... });
```

So you can call the `Router` directly via an object inside the closure to define your routes if you would like.

If you want to get a route parameter you have to do that in a middleware or Controller which is after the route has been matched and dispatched through the pipeline. At the point of defining routes (your routes file) nothing has been dispatched yet, these are just definitions.

All of this is ran before a route is matched and dispatched so there are no parameters at this point.

You should make a middleware that gets the locale from that route parameter of the Request and assigns it as needed.

Comment: so if I want to use middleware first of all I must do like this Route::get('setlocale/{locale}',function($lang){
       \Session::put('locale',$lang);
       return redirect()->back();   
});   but my route is group and I want to set prefix for that

Comment: why would you need to redirect back to something ... the middleware can be assigned to the group you currently have, you can then get the locale in the middleware and assign it to what is needed and just let the request pass through, all the routes will be taking that parameter though, so you can have the middleware forget that route parameter so it doesn't have to be passed to each controller method for those routes

Comment: no no that was a sample code. the session was important . I have to set a session with location variable that user use for example fa en and ... with $lang but when I use $lang in dd() it gives me object like top not "en" or "fa" or ....

Comment: when you execute this where? code doesn't get ran in the route files, they are just for registering routes

Comment: ok how can I find what lang the user want to show without $locale?